# Membership system

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone suggest a good membership structure?

For example, user paid for 1 month membership, starting 1.2.2012 ending 1.3.2012.

When and where is the best way to check if user is still a member or not?

Users are ranked with numbers in database (1-regular 2-member 3-moderator).

Comment: Could you please ask a specific question, with ways of evaluating the answers? Can you show what you've tried before? How do we know what "good" means? What are the requirements?

Comment: I just want to know when is the best way to check if date is still valid regarding the lenght of membership and changing the level from 2 back to 1 if not. Should i do this every login?

Comment: If the member status is calculated, you probably don't want to store it in the database. Calculate it and store it in the session.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps creating a table of Memberships with a start and end date, and an FK to the User.

Comment: Because the OP mentioned it while describing the domain, that memberships have end dates. Thanks for the downvote dude -- we all know that this simple question is implementation-specific. It's not worth our time to digress into implementation details. (How do you know he doesn't have another requirement that does need the end date?)

Comment: You're naturally making a bunch of "what if" assumptions w/o knowing anything about the OP's domain or program requirements.